# Include bbPress topics and replies in WordPress search results?

Tags: functions, search, bbpress

I realize this deals with a plugin (bbPress) however I hope it's still considered relevant enough to WPSE since it deals with altering WordPress search results...

How can I ensure that bbPress topics and replies are included in WordPress Core search?

I've found a few pages on this, but not sure what is the best approach:

https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/plugin-snippet-hack-to-include-bbpress-topics-in-wordpress-search/

https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/bbpress-in-wordpress-search-results/

https://gist.github.com/ntwb/7363a1de1184d459f0c3